# A game consists of rolling a die 8 times. You win if the result is 5 or 6.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, data-analysis

A game consists of rolling a die 8 times. You win if the result is 5 or 6. Your numbers of wins will be recorded.

a) Identify the discrete random variable, X
ans: Each time you role a die, if the result is 5 or 6, you win the game

b) State the number of trials, n

ans: As it is stated 8 is number of trials

c) State the probability of success, p, in any trial

ans: 1.52* 10^-4

d) State the probability of failure, q, in any trial.

ans: 0.9999

Hi I was doing prctice questions and saw this question, I answered them but not really sure if the answers are correct. I checked online , it did not help me much.
I wouold appreciate it if you could help me see my answers are correct or not.

Comment: It is all incorrect except for (b).  Where did you come up with those values?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: If it helps, I think a "trial" here refers to a single roll of the die not all 8 rolls, as you seem to have (correctly) calculated.

Comment: "You win if the result is 5 or 6"  The result of *what* is 5 or 6.  If you roll 8 times the result will be 8at least* eight, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having rolled the die eight times, we are interested in counting how many (if any) of those times a 5 or 6 was rolled.

We give a name to this "counting of how many 5's or 6's"... we call it a random variable and it is customary to name a random variable $X$.

That is to say, $X$ is a way of looking at the results of our eight rolls of dice and being able to say aloud "*there were three 5's or 6's*" or "*there were no 5's and no 6's*" etc...

$X$ has "*support*" $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ as these are the possible answers to the question of "*how many 5's or 6's did we roll in our 8 rolls of the dice.*"

It can be said that our random process consists of several smaller identical independent "*trials*"... each of which correspond to a single roll of a die.  A "*success*" in one of these smaller trials correspond to us getting a 5 or 6 on the die.

The probability of success in a specific trial is going to simply be $\dfrac{1}{3}$ as it is assumed that the dice used are standard fair six-sided dice and two of the six sides correspond to a "win" here.

The probability of failure in a specific trial is going to simply be $\dfrac{2}{3}$, the opposite of the probability of success.

---

The answers as I would have written it:  a) $X$ is the random variable counting the total number of successes across all trials.  b) There are $n=8$ trials.  c) The probability of success for a specific trial is $p=\dfrac{1}{3}$.  d) The probability of failure for a specific trial is $q=1-p=\dfrac{2}{3}$

We call $X$ "*binomially distributed*" in this case and abbreviate all of the above into one statement, $X\sim\text{Bin}(8,\dfrac{1}{3})$

We can now talk about the probability that $X$ gives a certain value, i.e. that we rolled a certain number of 5's or 6's.  We have that the probability of us rolling $k$ 5's or 6's will be:

$$\Pr(X=k)=\binom{8}{k}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{8-k}$$

This information was not needed however for the parts of the question which you asked though it may likely appear in a followup question or parts of the question which you did not yet write.